# Why doesn't my keyframe animation for link color work in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

Using `@keyframes` (and `animation`) to animate `a` color does not work in Chrome.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ed3pypwr/
In Chrome the link stays blue. In Firefox it goes from red to green as expected. On a `div` it works fine in Chrome as well.

Is there any way to solve this?

**EDIT**
I know it should be prefixed with `-webkit-` to ensure maximum compatibility, but this is not the issue here. It does not work anyway.

**EDIT 2**
A solution would be to put the link in a wrapper and use `currentColor`: https://jsfiddle.net/b84gttu6/. Is there a better way ?

Comment: color:inherit would work just as fine

Comment: @RonaldUlyssesSwanson Yeah right, but I would rather find another way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Old versions (<43) of Chrome use the prefixed `@-webkit-keyframes` instead of the standard `@keyframes`. So full support would look like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes test
{
   from { color: red; }
   to { color: green; }
}
@keyframes test
{
   from { color: red; }
   to { color: green; }
}
```

**Update**:

I've been doing some tests with various different methods and it works only if the link has not been visited (why, I don't know).

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ed3pypwr/5/)

Comment: Use both to support all major browser!

Comment: As it is just a small example, I did not wanted to add every prefix to clarify. Chrome currently supports the unprefixed version.

Comment: By the way you should try, it still does not work with the prefixed version.

Comment: Well if you don't want to prefix everything you should look at a CSS-compiler and I think Chrome has only recently added support for the unprefixed version and not a lot of people are using the latest Chrome. Take a look here: http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation

Comment: Only Chrome 43 and higher supports animation without a prefix

Comment: I know, I wouldn't do that on production. As I said, this is just for the demo, and even prefixed, it does not work.

Comment: I've always been vocal about how extremely backwards Chrome is in these things, but the fact that the latest stable version *does* support the feature unprefixed makes this inaccurate at best and irrelevant at worst. The latest stable version *does* exhibit the issue described (and it doesn't help Chrome's case one bit considering they had far longer than *anyone* else to perfect *their own feature* - 8 whole years in total - worse still if it turns out to be a *regression*).

Comment: Isn't Chrome an evergreen browser? e.g. every Chrome user should be on the latest version, or at least n - 1?

Comment: @TylerH: Some users have autoupdate disabled, either by choice or circumstance.

Comment: @BoltClock And they should be catered to? On non-evergreen browsers where longterm support on snapshot versions is standard, I can understand, but breaking the fundamental functionality of an evergreen browser shouldn't be something developers should design around. The reason people moved to Chrome in the first place was standards compliance and new features... how ironic :-)

Comment: I've made an update. I'll keep messing around with it though.

Comment: One good thing to do is to start using Sass with a library such as Bourbon, where you just have to @include keyframes and the library fixes cross-browser support behind the scenes

Comment: @imtheman Oh, I did not notice that. That probably explains it indeed.

Comment: "it works only if the link has not been visited" In that case it may well be Chrome being a little overzealous with the whole :visited privacy thing. Unfortunately, that stuff isn't specified much beyond "UAs may do what they think is best in the interests of privacy". Using the currentColor workaround now given by the OP leaves Chrome none the wiser, though.