# href attribute stops text having css3 animation

Tags: css, animation, anchor, href

I'm in the process of building a website and I need to make the navigation bar have flashing text (fades from blue to red to blue). However, I have found that when the  tag has a href attribute inside it, the whole animation stops working. It's really critical both the words flash and the link still works

CSS code:

```
#menu-item-142 a
{
 animation-name: color_change !important;
 animation-duration: 1s !important;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite !important;
 animation-direction: alternate !important;
}

@keyframes color_change
{
  0%   { color: red;  }
  50%  { color: blue; }
  100% { color: red;  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<li id="menu-item-142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142">
<a title="appform" href="http://essex-van-hire.com/application-form/">Application Form</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The @keyframe rules is not working on visited links in Chrome.

Others users ask a related questions:

[Visited links lose CSS color animation in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212569/visited-links-lose-css-color-animation-in-chrome)

[Why doesn't my keyframe animation for link color work in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985933/why-doesnt-my-keyframe-animation-for-link-color-work-in-chrome)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It sucks that this hasn't been fixed, real problem for me.