# Strange CSS Animation issue with <a> tag overriding animation in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation

I am making a forum using MyBB and the HTML and CSS is pretty straight forward. I have a custom rank that should be making a rainbow animation using keyframes, here's the CSS for it (no problems):

```
.rainbowUser {
    color: rgb(255,0,0) !important;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-animation-name: colorRotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-name: colorRotate;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-name: colorRotate;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-name: colorRotate;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: colorRotate;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.2% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    49.8% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.4% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.2% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    49.8% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.4% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.2% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    49.8% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.4% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.2% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    49.8% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.4% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
@keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.2% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    49.8% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.4% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The animation plays fine and works on [this](http://supernova-networks.co.uk/forum/member.php?action=profile&uid=2) page, but doesn't work anywhere else. Moving the element out of the  tag that it is contained in makes it work. Here's the  tag code taken from developer tools:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #005ea7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #005ea7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
user agent stylesheeta:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

tag and span HTML:

```
<a href="http://supernova-networks.co.uk/forum/member.php?action=profile&amp;uid=3" original-title="">
<span class="rainbowUser" original-title="">[S-N] Bena</span>
</a>
```

I'm really not quite sure what to do. This also only happens on Chrome and works absolutely fine on every other browser I've tried.

Thanks very much.

Comment: This probably won't solve your problem, but I recommend using the CSS shorthand for animation, so that you have less lines of CSS and it will load faster - `animation: colorRotate 1s infinite`. What color is displaying when it's "not working". If I had to venture a guess, I'd say it's inheriting the `a:link` or `a:visited` styles.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for not using shorthand. It's just easier to manipulate with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this seems to be a Chrome bug which has never been resolved. This is a solution to your problem, although it may not be the best one.

Change

```
<a href="http://supernova-networks.co.uk/forum/member.php?action=profile&amp;uid=3" original-title="">
    <span class="rainbowUser" original-title="">
        [S-N] Bena
    </span>
</a>
```

To

```
<span class="rainbowUser" original-title="">
    [S-N] Bena
    <a href="http://supernova-networks.co.uk/forum/member.php?action=profile&amp;uid=3" original-title="">
    </a>
</span>
```

Also, add the property `cursor: pointer` to rainbowUser in your css.

Now a bit of jQuery to fix the span not directing  the user to the correct page.

```
$(".rainbowUser").click(function () {
    var link = $("a", this).attr("href");
    window.location = link;
});
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks very much, I can probably tweak the templates for this.

Answer (score 1):

Until the Chromium team fixes this bug (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506898) you can use the CSS-only workaround suggested here: [Why doesn't my keyframe animation for link color work in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30985933/5554120)